# how to use bootstrap for the field that's being displayed with {{ form|crispy }} for django

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have a field `main_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=('image'))`
 in my model. and using my forms.py

```
    class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
```

I display the form that user can post image in my template simply with

```
{{ form|crispy }}
```

but it's so ugly I want to use bootstrap to decorate it. Is there a way to use bootstrap in forms.py with some widget? any advice on how I should do it please....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In settings.py file, you must add the below line to force `crispy` to use `bootstrap3` template pack.

```
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3'
```

And don't forget to add `crispy_forms` in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

And also you need to include `fields` attrib inside the `Form` `Meta` class.

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

This would show you all the fields present inside the db model class.

Comment: I already had that in settings.py, just don't know how to use it. and I'm excluding some fields...didn't post the whole thing. do you know how I can use some features of bootstrap for {{form}?

Comment: `{{ form|crispy }}` would apply bootstrap 3 styles to the form.